# Show an equation of a line passing through $P$ and parallel to the line given by $ax+by+c=0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

**Question:** A person considers lines on the plane $\mathbb{R^2}$ to be solutions of equations of the form $ax+by+c=0$, where $a,$ $b,$ and $c$ are fixed reals satisfying $a^2+b^2\neq0$.  Give a point $P=(x_0,y_0)$ show an equation of a line passing through $P$ and parallel to the line given by $ax+by+c=0$.

**My work so far:**

Lines that are parallel have the same slope.
So, if I put $ax+by+c=0$ into slope intercept form, I end up with $y=\frac{-ax}{b}-\frac{c}{b}$.  So my slope is $m=\frac{-a}{b}$.  Using this information, I will find the y-intercept using the point $P$.  So I get: $b=y_0-(\frac{-a}{b})x_0$ $\Rightarrow$ $b=y_0+\frac{a}{b}x_0$.  Now, putting all this information together, back into the slope intercept form I have: $y=\frac{-a}{b}x+y_0-(\frac{-a}{b})x_0$.

I'm not sure if any of this is correct or not.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know $b \neq 0 $? maybe you need to consider the $b=0$ case separately.

Comment: For an easier approach, note that the lines parallel to $ax+by+c=0$ have equations of the shape $ax+by+k=0$.

Comment: How would you go about showing that with those two equations?

Comment: Plug in $x=x_0$, $y=y_0$ and thus find $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All lines parallel to
$ax+by+c=0$
are of the form
$ax+by+d=0$
for some $d$.

If the parallel line
passes through
$(x_0, y_0)$,
then
$ax_0+by_0+d=0$
or
$d=-ax_0-by_0$.

The line is therefore
$ax+by-ax_0-by_0=0$.

Note:
I know this is substantially equivalent
to some of the other answers,
but I wanted to express it more simply.

Comment: Would you do anything with the other information provided in the problem?  This is where I am confused, we have been given the information of $a^2+b^2\neq0$ and I'm not sure if we need to use this or not in our solution?

Comment: If both $a=0$ and $b=0$, then the equation $ax+by+c=0$ reduces to $c=0$, which is not the equation of a line. If $c=0$, then it's the whole plane, because any point $(x,y)$ satisfies it. If $c\neq0$, then it's an empty set of points. Including $a^2 + b^2 \neq 0$ in the question just rules out the case where both are $0$, so that all you're left with are valid linear equations.